# Z3 dies while interacting with a Java program

Tags: java, z3

I have a Java program that launches a Z3 process and interacts with it by capturing its stdin/out, sending SMTLIB2 commands and reading its answers.

On OSX this works fine, but on Linux it often happens that while reading from its stdout Z3 unexpectedly dies with error code 139.

What does this error code mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409443/bit-vector-tactic-leads-to-exit-code-139-in-z3py - what version of Z3 and what is the code that causes 139?

Comment: Linux systems return errono 128+signal when a signal received. 128 + 11 = 139 . SIgnal 11 is SIGSEV (i.e. segmentation violation). = There is a memory access bug in some C++ code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the version of Z3 is 4.4.1. Today I cloned and built the master branch of Z3 and seems that the issue is fixed.

Comment: +1 for "What does this error code mean?".  This is not a duplicate, it's a different API and asks what the code means, which is answered in the comments and not in that other question.  Maybe you can post that as your own answer and accept it when the time runs out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was contributed in the comments.  From MikeJRamsey56, The code 139 is 128 + 11, where 11 is SIGSEV, a segmentation violation.  From the OP, this seems to have been a bug in Z3 4.4.1 that has since been fixed.